# Merging multiple panda frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of CSV files which contain data for a specific time and time is encoded as the filename:

```
time1.csv
Label val1 val2
a      5    6
b.     6    4

time2.csv
Label val1 val2
a      5    6
c      6    4

...
```

I can read each file into a Pandas data frame. Then I want to:
Add the "time" column into each data frame and then merge all the data frames into a single data frame.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What value the time column should contain? You should add the expected result to your question, like this its hard to say what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Given the list of filenames, you can assign a time column to equal the filename (excluding the last four characters, i.e. `.csv`) and concatenate the result.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(filename).assign(time=filename[:-4])
                for filename in filenames])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of your dfs times then iterate over it and append them to finaldf

```
finaldf =pandas.DataFrame()
for df in times:
    finaldf = finaldf.append(df.assign(time= timename),ignore_index=True)

print(finaldf)
```

to do it more automatically you can put filesname in an array and read it in the loap as well like this:

```
finaldf =pandas.DataFrame()
times = ['time1','time2']
for csv in times:
    df = pd.read_csv('{}.csv'.format(csv))
    finaldf = finaldf.append(df.assign(time= csv),ignore_index=True)
    
print(finaldf)
```

the result would be :

```
Label val1 val2   time
a      5    6     time1
b      6    4     time1
a      5    6     time2
c      6    4     time2
```

Comment: Isnt the request to merge pandas or concat pandas?

Comment: I added the final output of my code. You can also use "concat". merge used to merge two dfs on some columns, not concat by columns or by rows

Comment: This solution is known as a quadratic copy and grows exponentially slower: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489576/why-does-concatenation-of-dataframes-get-exponentially-slower

Comment: @Alexander I dont think for such number of files it makes it slower. it may get slower for loops bigger than 10000. But your solution works fine as well.

Comment: Create 100 files and time the results between the two methods.  It will become clear why one should avoid appending to dataframes within a loop.

Comment: @k2k2e6 you can use. 
finaldf = pd.concat([finaldf,df])
in the povided code

Comment: No, that won’t make it any faster. I suggest you read the link I provided.